# Highchart's x-axis not displaying correct data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have a table called `monthly flagged` with the following structure:

```
id
month
year
total_flagged
```

The way it works is that when a post is flagged, it will check the current month and year, if the year exists in the database, it will just `+1` to total flagged, else it will create a new row. For example, currently I have 1 row in my database:

```
id: 1
month: April
year: 2016
total_flagged: 28
```

If a user flags a post on May 1st, a new row will be be generated to `month: May`.

Now, I am trying to display this data on Highchart's. The y-xis shows number of flagged posts, while the x-axis shows the months. With one row in the table, the chart displays like this:

[image]

Which is ok. Although ideally I would like to have all the months at the bottom, but the months which exist in the table, only they will show data.

Nevertheless, the issue start's when **more than one row** exists in the table. If I have both data for April and May (2 rows in table), the chart appears like this:

[image]

The number `10` displayed on the x-axis is the `total_flagged` for month April.

Here is how I am storing data:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$months = array();
$data = array();
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);
while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $months[]          = $get_data['month'];
    $data[]            = $get_data['total_flagged'];
}
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
```

On my JavaScript for Highcharts:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [<?php echo json_encode($months); ?>]
},
```

And

```
series: [{
            name: 'Flagged posts',
            data: [<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>]
        }
```

**Edit**:

Current PHP code:

```
<?php
$statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$months = array();
$data = array();
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);
while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $months[]          = $get_data['month'];
    //$data[]            = $get_data['total_flagged'];
    $data[] = $get_data['total_flagged'][0];
}

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
?>
```

JavaScript for Highcharts (In full):

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Flagged Posts',
            x: -20 
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: <?php echo json_encode($months); ?>
        },

        yAxis: {
            format: '',
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Number of flagged posts',
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Flagged posts',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

Current graph:

[image]

Comment: just before you set the months as categories, and the total_flagged as data, have you tried checking what values are there in the two arrays, months and data?

Comment: @RahulSharma - Thanks for your reply :) And no. I have very rarely used arrays, and therefore don't know how to check the value?

Comment: the bowser debugger can help you. just stick a break point where you are assigning values to the array.

Comment: @RahulSharma - Ok, so on my browser debugger, `$months` is showing with the value: `categories: [[ "April" , "May" ]]`. And `data: [["10", "25"]]` - All which are correct

Comment: @RahulSharma - Ok, there is progress, both April and May now show up on my x axis, but no data is being shown for them. For example, no line is being generated to say that April had 10 flagged posts etc..

Comment: @RahulSharma - Ok, I have made the changes you have specified above, editing my post to show you the current situation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing data:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare ($connect, "SELECT * FROM monthly_flagged");
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$months = array();
$data = array();
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);
while($get_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
    $months[]          = $get_data['month'];
    $data[]            = $get_data['total_flagged'];
}
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);
```

Categories and Series chart options:

```
xAxis: {
categories: <?php echo json_encode($months); ?>
}

series: [{
        name: 'Flagged posts',
        data: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
}
```